# Build custom pdf from users choices

Tags: customization, pdf

I would appreciate a bit of guidance on how we can achieve the following functionality on our Wordpress site:

1. Users click a selection of topics on a checkbox list
2. A custom pdf is created for them based on their choices that can be downloaded or emailed to them

Essentially we need this because we have a very long guide in pdf format and would like people to be able to select only the sections relevant to them and create a pdf.

We could transfer the content from the pdf to wordpress pages/posts if that would help.

Comment: Your question is quite broad. Have you done any research on the subject? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an industrial strength solution, you might consider AppendPDF by Appligent (and/or other products from them). As a command line application, it is very easy to integrate and to run.

Alternatively, there are several libraries (such as iText, pdflib, etc.) which could be used to create such customized documents.

Ah, yeah, and if you want an enterprise product, you might look at the LiveCycle Document Server by Adobe, which is industrial strength, and absolutely viable for this task.